# cannot insert query result into file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I try to insert result of query into some file.
The file is created but it contain nothing.
I check the query result and its working, i receive a result data.

here is my controller code :

```
$members_nik = array();
$members_nik = select_config_by('member', 'member_nik', 'WHERE 1=1');
file_put_contents("data.txt", implode(', ', $members_nik));
```

here is my function code :

```
function select_config_by($table, $obj, $where){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT $obj as result FROM $table $where");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$result = $row['result'];
return $result;}
```

Comment: there is a typo in your variable name in the implode function.  it should be `implode(', ', $members_nik)`

Comment: @BizzyBob
now i'm getting new error .
implode(): Invalid arguments passed.

Comment: You are getting that error becuase `$member_nik` is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returing a string from the `select_config_by` function but then trying to implode it as if it were an array.

Now assuming you want to return all the results and save them in your `data.txt`, change the function to this:

```
function select_config_by($table, $obj, $where)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT $obj as result FROM $table $where");
    $temp = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $temp[] = $row['result'];
    } 
    return $temp;
}
```

Comment: You are right, it's my bad assumption of the query.
but now the result still empty.

Comment: Try dumping the value of the array thats being returned. Is it empty or has values?

Comment: well, i know there is no value in text file because there no error now.
but when i use 
`$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,count($members_nik));
fclose($file);` it contain "1".

Comment: Why are you doing `file_put_contents("data.txt", implode(', ', count($members_nik)));`?  remove count and do this: `file_put_contents("data.txt", implode(', ', $members_nik));`

Comment: i'm just trying to get some result. since my code doesn't give any result.
here is my latest code.
`$members_nik = array();`
  `$members_nik = select_kolom('members', 'member_nik', 'WHERE 1=1');
  ob_start();
  var_dump($members_nik);
  $result = ob_get_contents();
  file_put_contents("data.txt", implode(', ', $members_nik));`

Comment: ok, just checking again all of my code, then it's really working.
thanks for your help.